# Encoding issues within sitemap.xml

Tags: xml, sitemap

Despite conforming to [sitemaps.org protocols](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) re: encoding, I'm getting errors from web crawlers.

One of which is YandexBot (http://yandex.com/bots).

The proper URL is: `http://example.com/events/2012/5/4/bananas'-fault`

The sitemap.xml encoded URL is `http://example.com/events/2012/5/4/bananas&apos;-fault`

YandexBot actually tries to use `&apos;` in the URL. If I don't encode the `'` as `&apos;`, the URL gets truncated by BingBot.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact Yandex (and other problematic crawlers) and let them know they should conform to the protocol. The issue is on their side to solve...

Comment: Believe it or not, Bing had a problem parsing correctly encoded sitemap.xml URLs! I haven't had any issues after they fixed the problem on their end. I suppose I'll have to keep vigilant.